# Want month wise net amount and mandays in sql when a date range is selected fromdate to todate

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT  T0.[U_BRANCH] 'branch',sum(T1.[U_NETAMT]) 'Net amount',sum((CASE when T1.[U_HRSWKD]>0 then 1 else 0 end)) 'mandays' 
FROM [dbo].[@MLD_OLBRATTD]  T0  
INNER JOIN [dbo].[@MLD_LABATTD1]  T1 ON T1.[DocEntry] = T0.[DocEntry] 
Where T0.[U_STARTDT]>=@FromDate and T0.[U_STARTDT]<=@ToDate and T1.[U_HRSWKD]>0
group by T0.U_BRANCH

branch   Net amount     mandays
TOONG   1483651.896266  5345
MRF     2480092.992900  11952
TEJO    1311481.288500  4834
```

Want month wise query 
here condition are

```
Declare @FromDate As DateTime
Declare @ToDate   As DateTime
Set @FromDate='20190401'--{?FromDate}
Set @ToDate ='20190730'--{?ToDate}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

`DATEPART` function will return the specific part in a date column. Using `MONTH`, you can get the desired output.

```
SELECT  T0.[U_BRANCH] 'branch'
    ,DATEPART(MONTH,T0.[U_STARTDT]) [Month]
    ,sum(T1.[U_NETAMT]) 'Net amount'
    ,sum((CASE when T1.[U_HRSWKD]>0 then 1 else 0 end)) 'mandays' 
FROM [dbo].[@MLD_OLBRATTD]  T0  
INNER JOIN [dbo].[@MLD_LABATTD1]  T1 ON T1.[DocEntry] = T0.[DocEntry] 
Where T0.[U_STARTDT]>=@FromDate and T0.[U_STARTDT]<=@ToDate and T1.[U_HRSWKD]>0
group by T0.U_BRANCH,DATEPART(MONTH,T0.[U_STARTDT])
```

Comment: PERFECT Thanks for your help

Comment: @Piyush, You are welcome. If you are found this answer is correct, then accept this answer. This will help others.